# Add a small video clip as background

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, video

I have an app and would like to have a video loop in the background of my initial view.  It will serve as my home screen and menu and will have buttons overlaying on top of it.  I have looked around but can't seem to find a guide or tutorial on this.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it off hand, but that's going to eat through battery like none other and, depending on your app, could be incredibly distracting. If you're doing something like a game, it may make sense but if you're doing a different kind of app, it is going to produce a horrible user experience. Are you sure you can't achieve the same effect through something like an animation?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Berg.  I was thinking about doing something similar to Vine.  As far as animation, I did think about slowly changing gradient colors, but am not 100% sure on how to do that either.  Again, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for what is probably the most approachable way to attack the video idea.

MPMoviePlayerController will very quickly let you present a fullscreen interface, but will require a bit more work to use it "in-line" which is what you are describing.

Otherwise you'll find yourself wandering down the AVAsset path, which will allow far more control over what is happening, but will require quite a bit more code to configure.

As far as 3rd party options go, using [the excellent GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) will allow you to throw a video at a view quite seamlessly and with very little code written on your part (the "SimpleVideoFileFilter" project in the examples can show you the way). But since you are merely displaying a video, this would be a significant amount of bloat for your project.

Bigger picture, using Animations instead of a movie has lots of appeal, for the performance, battery life, and general responsiveness of your app reasons stated by others.